# Playwright tests are not running on gitlab CICD

Tags: gitlab, playwright, cicd

**Hello**,

While my Playwright tests are running perfectly on my local machine, on a remote gitlab machine they all fail.
The output looks like this:

```
$ cd playwright
$ npm ci
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
> cd .. && husky install front/.husky
husky - Git hooks installed
added 236 packages, and audited 237 packages in 25s
70 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npx playwright install
Downloading Chromium 105.0.5195.19 (playwright build v1019)...
|                                                                                |   0% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■                                                                        |  10% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■                                                                |  20% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■                                                        |  30% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■                                                |  40% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■                                        |  50% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■                                |  60% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■                        |  70% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■                |  80% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■        |  90% of 133.2 Mb
|■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■| 100% of 133.2 Mb
Chromium 105.0.5195.19 (playwright build v1019) downloaded to /ms-playwright/chromium-1019

$ npm run ci:test
npx playwright test --config=src/configs/playwright.prod.config.ts
Running 30 tests using 10 workers
```

and then a bunch of red tests names lines indicating failure:

```
  ✘  2 [chromium] › account-settings.test.ts:12:3 › Account Settings functionality › validate account timezone modification (50s)
  ✘  3 [chromium] › account-settings.test.ts:16:3 › Account Settings functionality › validate adding api key (50s)
 page.goto: Timeout 50000ms exceeded.
       7 | test.describe('Account Settings functionality', () => {
       8 |   test('validate account phone number modification', async ({ page }) => {
    >  9 |     await validateChangePhoneNumber({ page });
         |           ^
      10 |   });
...
  29 failed
        at Object.Account Settings (/builds/dashboard-client/playwright/src/support/navigate/navigateToPage.ts:91:28)
        at navigationByPageName (/builds/dashboard-client/playwright/src/support/navigate/navigateToPage.ts:102:10)
        at validateChangeTimezone (/builds/dashboard-client/playwright/src/support/validate/validateAccountSettings/validateChangeTimezome.ts:12:9)
        at /builds/dashboard-client/playwright/src/tests/account-settings.test.ts:13:11
```

By looking at the recording it seems that the app is opened but no navigation step occurres until timeout exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies for Playwright are missing as indicated by the 'Downloading Chromium' progress indicators.

According to the documentation `npx playwright install --with-deps` will install the deps. Refer to: https://playwright.dev/docs/ci.

Comment: Using the official Docker image would avoid this issue

Answer (score 0):

Using the Playwright image will help you get started more quickly and with the needed deps in place.

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.39.0-jammy

stages:
  - test  

playwright:
  # image line can also go here if you want a job specific image
  before_script:
    - yarn install
  script:
    - yarn test --project=chromium
  environment:
    name: main
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - playwright-report
      - test-results
```